suddenly vs code stopped working
i am using vs code in Ubuntu for a past 3 months and it was working fine.Today I tried to open it, the app opens for a second and then closes itself. I did the Ubuntu software update still not opening.

What is "the software update thing"?

Ubuntu software update.

Try this solution and let me know if it works. It's mostly because of your VS code from Snap and it is faulty
